# Sharing configuration settings between Windows Azure roles

Tags: azure

My Azure project have Web Role and a worker Role. Both roles have some common configurations.

How I could share the configurations instead repeating for both roles.

Now the cscfg file looks like this

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="xxx" ....>
  <Role name="WebRole1">
     <Instances count="1" />
     <ConfigurationSettings>
        ....
        <Setting name="setting1" value="" />
        <Setting name="setting2" value="" />
      </ConfigurationSettings> 
     <Certificates>
     .....
     </Certificates>
  </Role>
  <Role name="WorkerRole1">
     <Instances count="1" />
     <ConfigurationSettings>
         ....
         <Setting name="setting1" value="" />
         <Setting name="setting2" value="" />
     </ConfigurationSettings> 
     <Certificates>
     .....
     </Certificates>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

After googling I found this http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/03/16/sharing-configuration-settings-between-windows-azure-roles/ - is there any simple way to achieve the same?

Comment: There's a suggestion for it on the Azure features request forum: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/3473871-support-a-shared-configuration-section-with-config (or search for "shared configuration")

Answer (score 2):

What you've found is really interesting approach, but the mentioned attachment is missing anyway. It is also questionable what will happen if I still have some role-specific settings and I add it(them) to the specific role. That approach (most probably) is limited to providing same settings for all the roles.

What I would do to achieve your goal is a bit different. I would use an Azure Table Storage to store my configuration settings. This might be a bit harder to implement the first time, but from then on, you are free to reuse it in all the projects. The `harder` bit is that you have to implement your own `monitoring` logic to monitor for configuration changes. And that's it. You have a common store for settings. You can read/update settings with any free or paid Azure Storage *explorer like tool.